# Liberar resultados PHP 7 PDO

Tags: php

alguien que conozca que funcion que se utiliza en PHP 7 para liberar resultados luego de una consulta. Porque conozco de mysqli_free_result(), pero creo que esta ya no se debe utilizar en PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando el driver mysqli, es del modo siguiente:

```
mysqli_free_result($sql);
```

Si usas PDO sería:

```
$sentencia->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alfredo Paz, disculpa, conoces tambien si se sigue utilizando en PDO set_charset(); ??

Comment: Ok,  Vale...!!!.

Comment: si, tan solo en este línea lo agregas al final, de este modo PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=futbol;charset=utf8", $usuario, $contrasenia);

Comment: Bien, y conoces si pdo utiliza una funcion nueva para escapar caracteres especiales de un string? Conozco mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes, real_escape_string, strip_tags, pero no se si pdo esta utilizando una nueva